# List all OU with Users

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm searching a way in PowerShell to list all OU with Users in it.

I tried something with `Get-ADUser` or `Get-ADOrganizationalUnit` but it doesn't really work.

Comment: What did you try _exactly_. Those would be the 2 cmdlets you need to use. How do you want to deal with recursive results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to get all of the OU's and check to see if they contain any users via `-SearchBase`. Filter them out with a `Where-Object` clause

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * | 
    Where-Object {(Get-ADUser -SearchBase $_.DistinguishedName -Filter *).Count -gt 0} | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply pull the OU from each user object. Then find unique values.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * |
    ForEach-Object {$_.DistinguishedName -replace '(^.*?)(OU=.*)','$2'} |
    Sort-Object -Unique
```

Note: this makes the assumption that you are not storing user objects in Containers rather than OUs